# Count the occurrencesfor the previous 10 days grouped by id? SQL Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to add a new column in my original dataframe that counts the amount of "A" status that the id had in the previous 10 days.
Columns ID, DateVal,       Status and   Class   should remain intact

My input

```
ID    DateVal       Status   Class   
1     2022-01-01    A        1      
1     2022-01-03    A        0      
1     2022-01-04    A        1       
1     2022-01-05    D        1       
1     2022-01-06    D        0      
1     2022-01-17    D        0      
2     2022-01-01    D        0       
2     2022-01-03    D        0
```

The output I expect:

```
ID    DateVal       Status   Class   New_col
1     2022-01-01    A        1       0      --> no previous "A" in 10 days for id 1
1     2022-01-03    A        0       1      --> 1 previous "A" in 10 days for id 1
1     2022-01-04    A        1       2      --> 2 previous "A" in 10 days for id 1
1     2022-01-05    D        1       3      --> 3 previous "A" in 10 days for id 1
1     2022-01-06    D        0       3      --> 3 previous "A" in 10 days for id 1
1     2022-01-17    D        0       0      --> no previous "A" in 10 days for id 1
2     2022-01-01    D        0       0      --> no previous "A" in 10 days for id 2
2     2022-01-03    D        0       0      --> no previous "A" in 10 days for id 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select *, countif(status = 'A') over(
    partition by id order by unix_date(date(dateVal)) 
    range between 10 preceding and 1 preceding
  ) as new_col
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: What if dateVal is a timestamp and we want to get the previous ones, regardless it's a day or an hour?
Got this error "Query error: ORDER BY key must be numeric in a RANGE-based window with OFFSET PRECEDING or OFFSET FOLLOWING boundaries, but has type TIMESTAMP at"

Comment: What I need is to get the 10 days before (including that day, but occurrences before),  not the 10 occurrences before. So if the same id have 2 A status occurrences on the same day, for the second one I need to count the first one + all the occurrences from 10 days before

Comment: It's not fully answerer because I said "previous 10 days" not "10 previous occurences". But ok, will post it again

Comment: that is exactly what my answer does!! `previous 10 days` that is what `range` is for vs. `rows`

Comment: if you need to include current day - just use `current row` instead of `1 preceding`

Comment: Won't work if I have 2 occurrences on the same day but minutes/hours before. Considering "current row" you'll get all occurrences on that day, even though it happened after - which give us a data leakage. Considering "1 preceding" it doesn't take into account occurrences on the same day (before that one)

Comment: This is a more complete question if you want to answer, with timestamp and 2 occurrence on the same day: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246515/count-previous-occurrences-from-x-days-before-within-the-same-id-sql-bigquer

Comment: Already got it. Just put unix_seconds instead of date and transform 10 days in seconds

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is correct, but to be more generic and take into account there're may be more than 1 occurrence per id per day:

```
    select *, countif(status = 'A') over(
        partition by id order by unix_seconds(dateVal)
        range between 864000 preceding -- 10 days in seconds
        and 1 preceding -- 1 second preceding
      ) as new_col
    from your_table
```